# Sort Array by time in the value while maintaining the name

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time

I have the following array:
Array ( [10] => 06:30pm [20] => 04:00pm [30] => 05:15pm )

The number in [] is the id and follow by the value is time. I need to sort this array by time while maintaining the id like this

Array ( [20] => 04:00pm [30] => 05:15pm [10] => 06:30pm )

Please also note that the time can be in AM or PM also.

I would then need to extract the id in the [] as comma separated value.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$time= ['10' => '06:30pm','20' => '04:00pm', '30' => '05:15am'];
$temp_time=array();
foreach ($time as $key => $value) {
    if(sizeof(explode("pm", $value))>1){
        $data=explode(":", $value);
        $data[0]=(int)$data[0]+12;
        $value=$data[0].':'.$data[1];

    }else{
        $data=explode(":", $value);
        if($data[0]=='12'){
            $value='00:'.$data[1];
        }else{
            $value=$data[0].':'.$data[1];
        }
    }
    $temp_time+=[$key => $value];
}
asort($temp_time);
$new_time=array();
foreach ($temp_time as $key => $value) {
    $new_time+=[$key => $time[$key]];
}
print_r($new_time);
```

output:

```
Array ( [30] => 05:15am [20] => 04:00pm [10] => 06:30pm )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare):

```
$source_array = array(10 => '06:30pm', 20 => '04:00pm', 30 => '05:15pm', 40 => '04:00am');

function arr_swap_elements(&$arr, $a_index, $b_index) {
    $tmp = $arr[$a_index];
    $arr[$a_index] = $arr[$b_index];
    $arr[$b_index] = $tmp;
    return;
}

function arr_sort_by_time(&$source_array, $start_index = 0, $arr_keys = null, $arr_len = null) {
    if (is_null($arr_keys)) {
        $arr_keys = array_keys($source_array);
    }
    if (is_null($arr_len)) {
        $arr_len = count($source_array);
    }
    for ($i = $start_index; $i < $arr_len; $i++) {
        if ($i > 0) {
            if (strtotime($source_array[$arr_keys[$i]]) > strtotime($source_array[$arr_keys[$i - 1]])) {
                $was_swapped = true;
                arr_swap_elements($source_array, $arr_keys[$i], $arr_keys[$i - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($start_index + 1 < $arr_len) {
        arr_sort_by_time($source_array, $start_index + 1, $arr_keys, $arr_len);
    }
}

arr_sort_by_time($source_array);

var_dump($source_array);
```